# Passing fstream ">>" as function argument

Tags: c++, operators, iostream

I'm writing a program reading a file containing two values in each line. Those values should be stored in two vectors, xVals and yVals. Therefore I use the push_back-function, but I want my code to be more beautiful. Now it's like:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("foo.txt");
double TempVal;
while(file >> TempVal){
    xVals.push_back(TempVal);
    file >> TempVal;
    yVals.push_back(TempVal);
}
```

What I am currently looking for is a solution like this one (just the important line):

```
while(file >> xVals.push_back(??) >> yVals.push_back(??))
```

The question marks stand for "I don't know how to get the value passed by ">>" there...
Is there an EASY (easier than the three lines above) or nicer way to achieve this? :-)

Thanks

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose, but what you call beautiful, I call **obfuscated**.

Comment: Do you really believe your code will be more beautiful when it is unreadable ?

Comment: Well, I could avoid a temporary variable ;-)

Comment: @Vincent:  If it can, the optimizer will eliminate temporaries you never even thought of.  Don't try to do the optimizer's job -- it's better at optimizing your code than you could ever hope to be.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I assume such an optimizer is included in the gnu compiler collection? Didn't know of its existence. Sorry for the nooby question, I am learning this at the moment :-)

Comment: @Vincent:  Any modern compiler you are likely to use will have a powerful optimizer built in.  This includes both GCC and MSVC, to name only two.

Comment: Okay thank you. So @K-ballo's solution does do the job nice and simple in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
double tempX, tempY;
while( file >> tempX >> tempY )
{
    xVals.push_back(tempX);
    yVals.push_back(tempY);
}
```

If you truly wanted something *beautiful*, you would define a `Point` class that performs stream extraction/insertion, and then just use an algorithm:

```
std::vector<Point> points;
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator< Point >( file ), std::istream_iterator< Point >()
  , std::back_inserter( points )
);
```

Comment: +1 The first refactoring reflects the symmetry far better than the OP's code.

Comment: that (first one) would do it, but it uses two temporary variables. The second one I have to reflect of…

Comment: @Vincent: you have two temporal components, whats wrong with two temporary variables?

Comment: I use that last option a lot, but I always typedef the istream_iterator type.

Comment: Your first version is much more beautiful than the second.  I don't have to read it for 5 seconds to know exactly what it's doing, as opposed to the second version.

Comment: @John Dibling: The second version says _copy this file of pointers to this vector of pointers_. Its a matter of getting used to it, just as I'm sure you get used to the fact that right shifting a stream gets you content from a file...

Comment: @K-ballo:  I know what it does, that's not the issue.  The issue IMO is that with the second version I need to actually **read** the code to know what it's doing, whereas in the first version I can give it a cursory glance and my first impression will be correct.  By the way, you're missing a closing paren.

Answer (score 0):

Simply to avoid usage of the `TempVal` you could operate on the vector instances directly:

```
while(file.good() && !file.eof())
{
    xVals.resize(xVals.size() + 1,0.0);
    yVals.resize(yVals.size() + 1,0.0);
    file >> xVals.back() >> yVals.back();
}
```

Comment: Okay, this solution is also nice, but as stated above, temporary variables are not that bad as I thought of :-)

Comment: Please don't use `.eof()` as a loop condition. It almost always produces buggy code, as it does in this case. Your code performs an infinite loop when provided malformed input.

Comment: @Rob: Added check for the input stream. Better now? Explain further please if this doesn't help.

Comment: @g-makulik This code will still cause problems. `file.eof()` is not true until you read *past* the end of a file. So when you reach the end of the file your loop will run one more time and `file >> xVals.back() >> yVals.back();` will fail. A common way of avoiding this is writing your read loops like `while (file >> variable) { ... }`.

Comment: Will checking the result of the operator>> cure this problem, like `if(!(file >> xVals.back() >> yVals.back())) { break; }` ??

Comment: @g-makulik - It depends upon the rest of the loop. I imagine that you'll still have one too many `.resize()` calls on each vector.